# Magic Textures question

Tags: texturing, shaders

Is there a way to have the white areas be clear in this glass marble example?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the color output of the color ramp to mix in a Transparent BSDF with another mix shader node. Make sure the transparent BSDF is the bottom slot of the mix shader in this case.

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get it connected properly, what do I have connected wrong?
[marble2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXbdG.jpg)

Comment: Plug the output of the colorramp into the mix's _fac_ input and the output of this first mix into the material output. The connect the output of the second mix with the first input BSDF of the first mix.

Comment: I'm getting closer but lacking something....I tried the material on some text to hopefully be able to see the clear sections better   https://i.imgur.com/0LIHR5y.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Assign to blue and black on color ramp alpha=0. Make node color ramp alpha into mix shader factor. Change glossy into glass bsdf. For better effect you can add volume scatter/absorption shader. Connect it into volume material output. Hf:)